# Are there any macros to determine if my code is being compiled to Windows?

Tags: c++, c, operating-system, c-preprocessor

I would like to detect whether the OS I'm compiling on is Windows. Is there a simple macro I can check to verify that?

Comment: You might want to clarify whether you want to know Windows vs. Linux vs. Mac OS X vs. whatever or if you want to know Windows XP vs. Windows Vista vs. whatever.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

*[Edit: I assume you want to use compile-time macros to determine which environment you're on.  Maybe you want to determine if you're running on Wine under Linux or something instead of Windows, but in general, your compiler targets a specific environment, and that is either Windows (DOS) or it isn't, but it's rarely (never?) both.]*

Some compilers offer macros to indicate a Windows build environment.  But these will vary from compiler to compiler, and even on the same compiler on Windows if the target environment is *not* exclusively windows.  Usually it's `__WIN32__`, but not always.

```
#if defined (__WIN32__)
  // Windows stuff
#endif
```

Sometimes it can be `_WIN32`, `__CYGWIN32__`, or possibly just the compiler indicator (`_MSC_VER`).

If you know the environment you'll be building in (from the makefile) then you can usually pass in the `#define` on the command line, like "`g++ -D __WIN32__ yourfile.c`".

[A little more info here](http://predef.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 25):

There are a number of different ways to detect compilation, host, and runtime environments. All depending on exactly what you want to know. There are three broad types of environments:

- **Build**: This is the environment in which the program is compiled.
- **Host**: This is the environment in which the program is being run.
- **Target**: In case of code-generation tools (such as compilers), this is where the generated code will run.

If you are *cross-compiling*, the build and host environment can be completely different (this is common when building embedded applications, but not very common when building desktop/server apps), and you typically cannot run the compiled binary on the system used to compile it. Otherwise, the host environment must be compatible with the build environment: for example, building an application on XP which will run on Vista.

C preprocessor macros can not be used to tell you the details of the host system (i.e. what you are running on); they can only tell you what the code was compiled for. In the windows case, the two most important macros are:

- **_WIN32** signifies that the Win32 API is available. It does **not** tell you which compiler you are using, in fact _WIN32 is defined both when using Cygwin's GCC and MinGW's GCC. So, do not use _WIN32 to figure out if you're being compiled with Visual Studio.
- **`_MSC_VER`** tells you that you the the program is being compiled with Microsoft Visual C/C++. Well, almost. `_MSC_VER` is **also** defined when using Intel's C++ compiler which is intended to be a drop-in replacement for Visual C++.

There are a bunch of other macros described in the Visual Studio documentation.

If you want to know which exact version of Windows you are using, you'll have to use runtime functions such as GetVersion() (as described in other answers).

You might get more specific answers if you told us exactly what you want to check for.

Comment: Cygwin GCC only defines `_WIN32` when compiling a Win32 application (which is not a Cygwin app), which effectively makes it act as a MinGW compiler, so that makes `_WIN32` a nice OS check.

Comment: Additionally, `clang` [defines `_MSC_VER` and `_MSC_FULL_VER`  in MSVC compatibility mode](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#microsoft-extensions) and provides a `-fms-compatibility-version=` option to enable the features of different versions of MSVC, and set the feature-test macros accordingly.

Answer (score 16):

```
% touch foo.C ; g++ -dM -E foo.C
```

Will do a nice job of listing all the macros (#define's) automagically defined for you by your [machine specific] g++ compiler.

There might be something similar for Microsoft's compilers...

Comment: Or just `gcc -E -xc -dM /dev/null' if you don't want to leave a temp file behind (replace `-xc` with `-xc++` for macros used with C++ instead of C).

Answer (score 12):

These three lines will help you with detection, first we or most of the predefined windows hints together into one OS_WIN macro definition:

```
#if defined(_WIN32) || defined(WIN32) || defined(__CYGWIN__) || defined(__MINGW32__) || defined(__BORLANDC__)
#define OS_WIN
#endif
```

Then you can check for it using the preprocessor ifdef:

```
#ifdef OS_WIN
//Windows specific stuff
#else
//Normal stuff
#endif
```

Comment: Well, there's really only one "good" macro to check, being `_WIN32`. I downvoted this one because well, Cygwin, isn't Windows. Although you could link to msvcrt.dll, Cygwin isn't meant for that. It's a whole different environment. `WIN32` or `__WIN32__` aren't described anywhere on msdn.com, and reading all predefined macros output by `gcc -dM -E` doesn't help at all with getting those that are only OS-dependent, which is what the question is about.

Answer (score 6):

The MSVC++ compiler (not `windows.h`) defines `_WIN32` for *all* builds, so it is a safer macro to check.  The MinGW gcc compiler does too.  Any cross-compilation environment targeting Win32 *should* set this too.

Answer (score 4):

If you're running MS Windows targeted code you can call GetVersion() or GetVersionEx() for more info, and to identify the variant of Windows you are running on.

For more info scope out the MSDN info.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724451(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 4):

This thing works in visual studio 2012, and
other cgwin's g++ compiler.
Cut and paste it around
but this is generally as thin as it gets
All it does is detect windows op systems.
Just apply quantification:
If not win
Then *inux
:D enjoy

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
Using namespace std;


int main(){    
    char chCap;    int i = 0;
    const int MAX_BUFFER = 70; 
    char buffer[MAX_BUFFER];

    string cmd="ver";   
    FILE *stream = _popen(cmd.c_str(), "r");

    if (0 != stream){
        while (!feof(stream)){  
            //One way is here
            //chCap = fgetc(stream);
            //cout << chCap;
            //buffer[i++] = chCap;

            //This one seams better
            fgets(buffer, MAX_BUFFER, stream);      
        }
        _pclose(stream);
    }       
    cout << endl;
    cout << buffer << endl;

    //The op sys detection starts here
    string opSys(buffer);   //char array to string
    if("Microsoft" == opSys.substr(0,9)){
        cout << "You are in a Microsoft envornment " << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;    
}
```

Comment: That's overkill. All the stuff after `_popen` is not needed. If `_popen` compiles, it's a Microsoft platform, else it's not.

Comment: @Mat-e If it used the popen and pclose, which works on MinGW, you may get a false positive from a user command ver.

Answer (score 3):

The links mentioned so far indicate information at compile time. You can set flags within those code segments at compile time.

However, I think what you are asking is more along the lines of "Which version of windows am I running under?"not "Am I compiled to run under windows?" I hope that's a correct assumption.

Under C#, it is relatively simple. You can reference System.Environment.OSVersion then look under "Platform".

However, you are asking about C++. What compiler are you using? THis makes a big difference as to how you check for a version of the operating system, as there is no single standard for getting this information (that I've found).

Under Visual C++, use Google to find info on GetVersion/GetVersionEx. Both will give you structures that contain information on the current version of Windows that the program is running under.

Answer (score 2):

Actually I would go with the Environment. getenv() is a standard library function and so is probably the only potentially portable way to do this. The trick is figuring out what variables are unique to all OSes. Windows has ComSpec, appdata, Windir, systemroot and systemdrive which should be set. You could also strstr the path variable for WINDOWS or WINNT but that might not be accurate. I'm not Linux shell/Solaris/MacOS expert so someone else might be able to tell you what "standard" environment variables exist in those OSes. CygWin may cause you some issues, too.