# C++ compiling on Windows and Linux: ifdef switch

Tags: c++, linux, windows, conditional-compilation

I want to run some c++ code on Linux and Windows.  There are some pieces of code that I want to include only for one operating system and not the other.  Is there a standard *#ifdef* that once can use?

Something like:

```
  #ifdef LINUX_KEY_WORD
    ... // linux code goes here.
  #elif WINDOWS_KEY_WORD
    ... // windows code goes here.
  #else 
  #error "OS not supported!"
  #endif
```

---

The question is indeed a duplicate but the answers here are much better, especially the accepted one.

Comment: @MooingDuck: I confirm that I wanted to decided on the target OS not necessarily on the compiler used.

Comment: [How to detect reliably Mac OS X, iOS, Linux, Windows in C preprocessor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5919996/995714), [Detect Windows or Linux in C, C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8666378/995714)

Answer (score 275, accepted):

use:

```
#ifdef __linux__ 
    //linux code goes here
#elif _WIN32
    // windows code goes here
#else

#endif
```

Comment: Hi I'm new to C++ programming, could you help me clarify something? In the line `#ifdef __linux__`, what is the `__linux__` part called?

Answer (score 84):

You can do:

```
#if MACRO0
    //code...
#elif MACRO1
    //code...
#endif
```

…where the identifier can be:

```
    __linux__       Defined on Linux
    __sun           Defined on Solaris
    __FreeBSD__     Defined on FreeBSD
    __NetBSD__      Defined on NetBSD
    __OpenBSD__     Defined on OpenBSD
    __APPLE__       Defined on Mac OS X
    __hpux          Defined on HP-UX
    __osf__         Defined on Tru64 UNIX (formerly DEC OSF1)
    __sgi           Defined on Irix
    _AIX            Defined on AIX
    _WIN32          Defined on Windows
```

Answer (score 48):

I know it is not answer but added if someone looking same in Qt

**In Qt**

https://wiki.qt.io/Get-OS-name-in-Qt

```
QString Get::osName()
{
#if defined(Q_OS_ANDROID)
    return QLatin1String("android");
#elif defined(Q_OS_BLACKBERRY)
    return QLatin1String("blackberry");
#elif defined(Q_OS_IOS)
    return QLatin1String("ios");
#elif defined(Q_OS_MAC)
    return QLatin1String("osx");
#elif defined(Q_OS_WINCE)
    return QLatin1String("wince");
#elif defined(Q_OS_WIN)
    return QLatin1String("windows");
#elif defined(Q_OS_LINUX)
    return QLatin1String("linux");
#elif defined(Q_OS_UNIX)
    return QLatin1String("unix");
#else
    return QLatin1String("unknown");
#endif
}
```

Answer (score 18):

It depends on the used compiler.

For example, Windows' definition can be `WIN32` or `_WIN32`.

And Linux' definition can be `UNIX` or `__unix__` or `LINUX` or `__linux__`.

Comment: There is such a standard. Those toolchains that don't adhere to it, are either buggy, stone-age old, or just bad.

Comment: `WIN32` is defined inside `Windows.h`. So, if the header was not included type switch won't work. `_WIN32` should be defined by default.

Answer (score 13):

This response isn't about macro war, but producing error if no matching platform is found.

```
#ifdef LINUX_KEY_WORD   
... // linux code goes here.  
#elif WINDOWS_KEY_WORD    
... // windows code goes here.  
#else     
#error Platform not supported
#endif
```

If `#error` is not supported, you may use static_assert (C++0x) keyword. Or you may implement custom STATIC_ASSERT, or just declare an array of size 0, or have switch that has duplicate cases. In short, produce error at **compile time** and not at **runtime**

Comment: `#error` **must** be supported (unlike `#warning` which is an extension). But I agree that it may not necessarily be the best way to fail a build.

Comment: @Thomas: Indeed. Fortunately, if `#error` is not supported in some non-compliant implementation, the result of the incorrect preprocessor statement is, well --- an error. And if it's not an error either, then the compiler is a *REALLY REALLY* crappy one and not worth supporting anyways (though I *highly* doubt such a compiler exists).

Answer (score 9):

It depends on the compiler. If you compile with, say, G++ on Linux and VC++ on Windows, this will do :

```
#ifdef linux
    ...
#elif _WIN32
    ...
#else
    ...
#endif
```

Comment: This will always do. All compilers implement this in the same fashion. Clang on linux mimicks GCC, Clang and GCC on Windows mimicks MSVC.

Comment: @rubenvb: All *existing* compilers, by *convenience*. This behavior is not standardized and may as well be different for some compilers nobody uses.

Answer (score 3):

No, these defines are compiler dependent. What you can do, use your own set of defines, and set them on the Makefile. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430424/how-can-i-detect-the-operating-system-in-c-c) for more info.

Comment: correct, but not helpful

Comment: @Cicada: Compiler dependent has no meaning when all compilers (worth talking about) do the same thing.

Comment: yet, there's no standard defining this, and that's what he asked for. I'm updating the answer to point it to an useful reference about this

Comment: I'm amused that you suggest makefiles as an alternative to "compiler dependent" defines.  More compilers use the same defines than use makefiles.

Comment: Compilers don't use makefiles, makefiles use compilers.

Comment: Makefiles are a rather unix-like solution usable on windows but not as common. For one thing make isn't installed by default.