# How to check if Xlib is used using #ifdef?

Tags: c++, x11

For example you can check if Windows is used by checking if "WIN32" macro is defined. And i would like to get the same behaviour but to check if Xlib is used. But i don't know what Xlib defines to know it's defined.
If you don't know what i mean here is an example:

```
#ifdef WIN32 //Check if WIN32 is defined
//Do something
#endif
```

And i would like to change this in a way that it does something when Xlib used.

I'm sorry if there are some grammatical errors but i'm not a native english speaker.

Comment: Just go find your `X11` header files. In `/usr/include/X11` there is `Xlib.h` which defines `_X11_XLIB_H_` or there is `X.h` which defines `X_H`.  `Xlib.h` is your friend though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The macro `WIN32` is only defined, if you included `#include <windows.h>` before or set the macro in your compiler flags (`-DWIN32`). For Xlib you could use the macro `X_PROTOCOL` very similar if you included `#include <X11/X.h>` before.

```
#ifdef X_PROTOCOL //Check if X_PROTOCOL is defined
//Do something
#endif
```

Another way would be to use `_XLIB_H_` if you included `#include <X11/Xlib.h>` before, but I wouldn't because identifiers beginning with an underscore are reserved to the implementation and there is no guarantee that this identifiers won't change.

Comment: Now, it looks to me that there is no way to determine whenever i should use Windows or Linux version of my code without any errors :/

Comment: @digitcrusher You may want to use `_WIN32` instead of `WIN32`, this will work without any include. See also: [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649936/c-compiling-on-windows-and-linux-ifdef-switch)

Comment: Can you make X_PROTOCOL or something else to work without any include?

Comment: @digitcrusher Unfortunately not, because the compiler itself can't know at compile time without the header, that you're targeting Xlib at all. But you could check if the target is linux with `#ifdef __linux__` or add a define for XLIB to your compiler settings/make file (i.e. `-DXLIB` and check in code `#ifdef XLIB` without needing any include).

Answer (score 1):

> you can check if Windows is used by checking if "WIN32" macro is defined

The `WIN32` macro is defined by default by compilers that target Windows OS. Its purpose is to let the program detect Windows OS API, not necessarily any graphic subsystem.

X11 is not and OS. It's *optional* userland software that installs and runs under many operating systems, including Windows. When compiling an X11 programs for Windows, WIN32 will be defined, just like for any other Windows program.

No compiler defines anything by default on a system where X11 is installed.

If you want to detect X11 at build time, your best bet is probably a meta-build tool like GNU autotools or CMake.