# How to identify platform/compiler from preprocessor macros?

Tags: c++, macros, cross-platform, c-preprocessor

I'm writing a cross-platform code, which should compile at linux, windows, Mac OS. On windows, I must support visual studio and mingw.

There are some pieces of platform-specific code, which I should place in `#ifdef .. #endif` environment. For example, here I placed win32 specific code:

```
#ifdef WIN32
#include <windows.h>
#endif
```

But how do I recognize linux and mac OS? What are defines names (or etc.) I should use?

Comment: Here is [OS macro define list](http://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/OperatingSystems/).

Comment: The dupe has a much better accepted answer.

Comment: The suggested duplicate is NOT the same question. That question asks only about identifying the operating system, whereas this question also asks about identifying the compiler, which is a very different thing.

Comment: @JBentley yet the accepted answer does not even mention compilers, and only talks about OSes (and one "platform"). Not to mention it's a terrible answer relative to what the dupe has to offer.

Comment: @rubenvb Then link the other question as a comment. Just because it has a better answer, doesn't make it a duplicate. The question is what determines whether it is a duplicate, not the answers. Closing this one only ensures we'll never get a good quality answer to the compiler-related part of the question, which the so-called "duplicate" cannot ever answer.

Comment: I definetely can re-accept better answer if it will appear. )

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I check OS with a preprocessor directive?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142508/how-do-i-check-os-with-a-preprocessor-directive)

Comment: You should rather use `_WIN32` instead of `WIN32`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9025708/mingw-not-defining-win32-error-in-preprocessor-directives

Comment: Nothing will save you on Solaris under Sun Studio.... Defines you may be used to seeing, like `__SSE2__` are not present. And there's no way to know which `-xarch=X` was specified, like `-xarch=sse4_2`, `-xarch=aes` or `-xarch=avx_i`.

Answer (score 148, accepted):

For **Mac OS**:

```
#ifdef __APPLE__
```

For **MingW** on Windows:

```
#ifdef __MINGW32__
```

For **Linux**:

```
#ifdef __linux__
```

For other Windows compilers, check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430424/how-can-i-detect-the-operating-system-in-c-c) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152016/detecting-cpu-architecture-compile-time/152067#152067) for several other compilers and architectures.

Comment: Does `__APPLE__` distinguish between OSX and iOS?

Comment: `__APPLE__` is set for both OS X and iOS. You can `#include <TargetConditionals.h>` inside `#ifdef __APPLE__`, which then gives you a `TARGET_OS_IPHONE #define`.

Comment: `__MINGW64__` is also available when one uses mingw64

Comment: Since `__MINGW64__` is referenced, think `_MSC_VER` for Windows/MSVC is worth a mention (which can also be used to check MSVC Version).

Comment: I'm sorry, but this answer is quite incorrect on all accounts and doesn't even answer the question.

Comment: `__MINGW64__` is not endorsed by the MinGW-w64 authors, instead you should check for `__MINGW32__`, `#include <_mingw.h>` if it's defined, and check for `__MINGW64_VERSION_MAJOR`.

Answer (score 67):

See: http://predef.sourceforge.net/index.php

This project provides a reasonably comprehensive listing of pre-defined `#defines` for many operating systems, compilers, language and platform standards, and standard libraries.

Comment: As of version 1.55, Predef is now included in [Boost C++ Libraries](http://www.boost.org/).

Comment: I know the rules were different when you posted this, but I'm going to have to ask you to edit this post to include more relevant details. Now a days link only answers are strongly discouraged, and I'd like to offer you the chance to save this post before its removal.

Comment: As this is the only answer that actually answers the question as stated in the title, and the question is very generic and relevant I strongly advice against removing it. I wouldn't call it a "link only" answer either.

Comment: @0x7fffffff: What possible benefit to anyone would there be in duplicating the content of the other answers into this one? If you believe it's really important to have a single definitive answer, then perhaps you should create such an answer yourself (it shouldn't be hard: just glue together the existing answers in some sensible order). Personally I have better things to do with my time, but as a moderator clearly SO is more important to you than to me.

Answer (score 49):

Here's what I use:

```
#ifdef _WIN32 // note the underscore: without it, it's not msdn official!
    // Windows (x64 and x86)
#elif __unix__ // all unices, not all compilers
    // Unix
#elif __linux__
    // linux
#elif __APPLE__
    // Mac OS, not sure if this is covered by __posix__ and/or __unix__ though...
#endif
```

**EDIT:** Although the above might work for the basics, remember to verify what macro you want to check for by looking at the [Boost.Predef reference pages](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/predef/doc/html/predef/reference.html). Or just use Boost.Predef directly.

Comment: use __linux __ instead, linux is not defined when compiling with GCC with GNU extensions disabled (ie -std=c++0x)

Comment: @Erbureth Fixed, but one should really use predef.sourceforge.net/index.php as in the highest rated answer.

Comment: @rubenvb: indeed. And it got too few votes still, I think :) ... I've turned to their site so many times.

Comment: For consistency (perhaps a little pedantic) : the first `#if` ask if defined, the  others test for value. If would be more consistent to do `#elif defined(__unix__) ` , etc, I think.

Answer (score 23):

If you're writing C++, I can't recommend using the [Boost](http://www.boost.org/) libraries strongly enough.

The latest version (1.55) includes a new [Predef](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/predef/doc/html/index.html) library which covers [exactly what you're looking for](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/predef/doc/html/predef/reference/boost_os_operating_system_macros.html), along with dozens of other platform and architecture recognition macros.

```
#include <boost/predef.h>

// ...

#if BOOST_OS_WINDOWS

#elif BOOST_OS_LINUX

#elif BOOST_OS_MACOS

#endif
```

Comment: Given that this is boost, this solution will work on different platforms/OSs AND different compilers.

Comment: *"I can't recommend using the Boost libraries strongly enough...."* - I've evaluated Boost three times. It can't pass an evaluation... Most of the bugs report were lucky if they were acknowledged. Lack of acknowledgement points to deeper problems in the engineering process. I believe preprocessor macros and built in C++ Standard Libraries are a safer choice.