# Create a new folder or directory in SDL

Tags: c++, sdl

Is there any way to create a directory using SDL?
I want something similar to the windows api function SHCreateDirectory().

I have been looking here
http://www.libsdl.org/cgi/docwiki.cgi/SDL_API
but there is nothing even close to it.

Comment: SDL is a multimedia library, but there is a file API: RWops.

Comment: If you decide to use Boost, check out the [create_directory function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html#create_directory)

Answer (score 2):

SDL doesn't expose an API for filesystem operations. [See this post on the same topic](http://forums.libsdl.org/viewtopic.php?t=6064&sid=3f71bdc48016381d6d72104e04c2e204)

You can use [Boost](http://www.boost.org/) or [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/products/) (use only the core package) for cross platform filesystem operations.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, use [`CreateDirectory()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363855%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES attr;
attr = NULL;
string folder_name = "test"
CreateDirectory(folder_name.c_str(), attr);
```

I haven't tested this code.

Comment: This is almost exactly what I am doing now! It defeats the purpose of using sdl for cross platform compatibility though

Comment: Use `mkdir` on Linux and Mac. Consider using [preprocessor macros](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4605893/176769) to identify the block of codes that should be compiled for a specific platform. Unfortunately, SDL doesn't provide this kind of feature.