# recvfrom only receive few packets after that it goes in waiting state

Tags: c++, sockets, camera, udp, packets

Hi I am new in Socket Programming and try to create a client server applciation using in which my server is Camera and client in my C++ application.
When I see the packet transfer between computer and camera it showing that camera is sending more than 150000 packets after that it stops. But when I am receving that I am able to receive `400 - 450 packets` at a time after that the `recvfrom` function goes to waiting state. and If I again run that exe file without stopping the previous one it again receive `400-450 packets`.

**Code for Receving Packets**

```
SOCKET out1 = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_UDP);
    if (out1 == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        cout << out1 << endl;
    }
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(3956);
    inet_pton(AF_INET, "192.168.1.140", &server.sin_addr);
    int serverLength = sizeof(server);

    connect(out1, (sockaddr*)&server, serverLength);
    while (1)
    {
        memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
        int bytesIn = recvfrom(out1, buf, 1444, 0, (sockaddr*)&server, &serverLength);
        if (bytesIn > 0)
        {
            cout << "Image Received :" << bytesIn <<packet_counter << endl;
            packet_counter++;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Not Received : " << endl;
        }
    }
```

I am running the .exe with the administrator rights.

So can anyone please tell me why the recvfrom function is going in waiting state.

Thanks in Advance.

**EDIT:-**

Sorry that I am providing the whole code.

```
  #include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <thread>
#include <WinSock2.h>

// Library
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

using namespace std;

//***** Function Decleration *****//
void _packetConfig(SOCKET);
void _sendPacket(SOCKET, const char*, int, int);

// Global Variable
sockaddr_in server;

//***** Main Function *****//
void main(char argc, char* argv[])
{
    WSADATA data;
    WORD version = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
    if(WSAStartup(version, &data) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        cout << "Can't Start Socket" << WSAGetLastError<<endl;
        return;
    }
    char buf[2000];

        SOCKET out1 = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_UDP);
        if (out1 == INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
            cout << out1 << endl;
        }
        server.sin_family = AF_INET;
        server.sin_port = htons(3956);
        inet_pton(AF_INET, "192.168.1.140", &server.sin_addr);
        int serverLength = sizeof(server);

        connect(out1, (sockaddr*)&server, serverLength);


        int packet_counter = 0;


        SOCKET out = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);

        _packetConfig(out);

        cout << "Inside Main" << endl;
        while (1)
        {
            //connect(out1, (sockaddr*)&server, serverLength);
            memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
            int bytesIn = recvfrom(out1, buf, 1444, 0, (sockaddr*)&server, &serverLength);
            if (bytesIn > 0)
            {
                cout << "Image Received :" << bytesIn <<packet_counter << endl;
                packet_counter++;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "Not Received : " << endl;
            }
        }

        WSACleanup();
}

//***** Function to Send Bytes to the Camera *****//
void _sendPacket(SOCKET sock, const char* s, int len, int i)
{
    int sendOk = sendto(sock, (const char*)s, len, 0, (sockaddr*)&server, sizeof(server));

    if (sendOk == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        cout << "Didn't Work" << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "\nSend Succesfully" << " " << i << endl;
    }
    char buf[2000];
    int serverLength = sizeof(server);
    int bytesIn = recvfrom(sock, buf, 2000, 0, (sockaddr*)&server, &serverLength);
    if (bytesIn > 0)
    {
        cout << "Message Received :" << bytesIn << endl;
    }
}

//***** Function to call the _sendPacket function and send commands to the Camera *****//
void _packetConfig(SOCKET sock)
{
    // 59 Commands and every command call _snedPacket function to send commands to camera  it will working properly
}
```

In the above code I have to first send this `59 commands` written in `_packetConfig` function then only camera will send `Image packets` I am receiving the reply of all that commands.

When I run wireshark also with that code I can see that after these 59 commands 
the camera is giving `3580*51` packets.i.e 51 frames and each frame contain 3580 packets

Comment: What is in `errno` after `recvfrom` fails?  Also, why create the socket as `SOCK_RAW`?  I think you want `SOCK_DGRAM`.

Comment: I am not getting error or not the else part is printing the code just stuck at recvfrom function after receiving 400-450 packets

Comment: No if I use SOCK_DGRAM I can't get the packet I don't know why as I said earlier I have not much idea about the sockets.

Comment: Please show the sending code (all of it).  Thx.

Comment: Should I show the whole code?

Comment: Is there a lot of it?  What I actually want to see how the socket is created and the code that calls `sendto()`.

Comment: Oh sorry for that. the sendto function is called from _packetConfig which is called from main().

Comment: And both the sockets are created in main

Comment: @ChandrapalSinghJhala You **absolutely** should be using `SOCK_DGRAM` on both ends, since you are using the UDP protocol. The ONLY time you should EVER use `SOCK_RAW` is when you want to implement a *custom* network protocol, or promiscuously capture all network packets (neither of which are necessary in this situation).  `SOCK_DGRAM` is the preferred socket type for UDP. Whatever notions you have about using `SOCK_RAW` are wrong. [I tried to explain that to you earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50999531/raw-sockets-in-c-windows/50999582#comment89000249_50999582).

Comment: @ChandrapalSinghJhala Can you provide the Wireshark capture?  Or at least a screenshot of a *complete* packet (or at least the packet headers before the image data) from the camera?

Comment: @ChandrapalSinghJhala where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for posting your code.  There are actually a few things wrong with it so first I will post some code that works as a reference and then mention the major issues I noticed with yours afterwards.

OK, here is some code that works for me:

```
#include <WinSock2.h>                   // ** before** windows.h
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <assert.h>

#pragma comment (lib, "ws2_32.lib")

const int port = 3956;

// main
int main (char argc, char* argv[])
{
    WSADATA wsadata;
    WORD version = MAKEWORD(2, 2);

    int err = WSAStartup (MAKEWORD (2, 2), &wsadata);
    if (err)
    {
        std::cout << "WSAStartup failed, error: " << err << std::endl;
        return 255;
    }

    char buf [1444];
    bool send = argc > 1 && _stricmp (argv [1], "send") == 0;

    if (send)
    {
        // Send
        SOCKET skt_out = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
        assert (skt_out != INVALID_SOCKET);

        sockaddr_in destination_address = { };
        destination_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
        destination_address.sin_port = htons (port);
        inet_pton (AF_INET, "192.168.1.2", &destination_address.sin_addr);
        memset (buf, 'Q', sizeof (buf));
        printf ("Sending: ");

        for ( ; ; )
        {
            sendto (skt_out, buf, sizeof (buf), 0, (const sockaddr *) &destination_address, sizeof (destination_address));
            printf (".");
            Sleep (50);
        }

        closesocket (skt_out);
        WSACleanup ();
        return 0;
    }

    // Receive
    SOCKET skt_in = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
    assert (skt_in != INVALID_SOCKET);

    int receive_buffer_size = 65536;
    if ((setsockopt (skt_in, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, (const char *) &receive_buffer_size, sizeof (int)) ) < 0)
        std::cout << "Could not set SO_RCVBUF, error: " << WSAGetLastError () << std::endl;

    sockaddr_in receive_address = { };
    receive_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    receive_address.sin_port = htons (port);
    receive_address.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl (INADDR_ANY);

    if (bind (skt_in, (const sockaddr *) &receive_address, sizeof (receive_address)) == -1)
    {
        std::cout << "bind failed , error: " << WSAGetLastError () << std::endl;
        return 255;
    }

    int packetCounter = 0;
    printf ("Receiving: ");

    for ( ; ; )
    {
        int bytesIn = recvfrom (skt_in, buf, sizeof (buf), 0, NULL, 0);
        if (bytesIn > 0)
            std::cout << "Packet received:" << bytesIn << " bytes (" << ++packetCounter << ")" << std::endl;
        else
            std::cout << "Receive error: " << WSAGetLastError () << std::endl;
    }

    closesocket (skt_in);
    WSACleanup ();
    return 0;
}
```

To run this in 'send' mode, specify **send** as the first argument on the command line.  Otherwise it acts as a receiver (aka server).

So what's wrong with your code?  Well, in no particular order:

- as we already said, you shouldn't be using `SOCK_RAW`
- you need to call `bind` on the receiving socket so that it knows what port to listen on.  The `sockaddr *from` parameter to `recvfrom` doesn't mean what you think it means (please check the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/api/winsock/nf-winsock-recvfrom)).  You will see I pass this as NULL.
- you were misinterpreting the return value from `WSAStartup`.  Again, please check the docs.

But having said all that, it was essentially the call to `bind` that you were missing.  I rewrote the code because yours is rather messy.

Also, important detail, UDP doesn't guarantee delivery - there are a number of reasons why a packet that has been sent does not get received or might even get received out of sequence (does your camera sequence the packets in some way?)
  You need to cater for that in the logic of your application (and it that's a problem, it's better to use TCP, which does guarantee packet delivery and sequencing).

Comment: Thank you Sir, It is working with SOCK_DGRAM and the system is capturing all the image packet but when I print anything inside recvfrom function then I think it miss to print the statement for all the packet receive.

Comment: Yes, it probably will.  If the sender sends packets faster than the receiver can read them then some will get quietly dropped _because UDP doesn't guarantee delivery_.  You should most likely actually be using TCP here, unless there's a _very_ good reason not to.

Comment: But the Camera is using UDP protocol. Is their any way so that I can receive all of them?

Comment: @ChandrapalSinghJhala use `setsockopt()` to increase the size of the socket's receive buffer. And make sure you are not wasting time processing packets between receives. Read as fast as possible, usually by reading and queuing packets in one thread and processing them in another thread.

Comment: @Chandra This sounds like a good idea. Sorry, I forgot you were streaming from a camera.  I have added it my answer (and got rid of `errno` - use `WSAGetLastError()` instead).

Comment: @RemyLabeau and PaulSanders Thank you sir for your guidance

Comment: You're welcome, good call by @Remy.  I added a note to my answer about packets being received out of sequence which you should at least be aware of.  It's unlikely to happen on a LAN, but across a wider area network it might very well happen.