# UDP client can't send message to server but can receive

Tags: c++, udp, client

I am trying to create a UDP client. When I try to send a message to the server I get a `WSAEOPNOTSUPP` error message. But the subsequent `recvfrom` call seems to work just fine. I haven't had a chance to test it with the server yet so I'm assuming the data will actually come back as expected. According to the documentation that error means

> MSG_OOB was specified, but the socket is not stream-style such as type
>   SOCK_STREAM, OOB data is not supported in the communication domain
>   associated with this socket, or the socket is unidirectional and
>   supports only receive operations.

Here is the code (sanitized for your protection)

```
WORD version = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
WSADATA data;
int error = 0;

if ((error = WSAStartup(version, &data)) != NO_ERROR)
{
    kzLogError(KZ_LOG_CATEGORY_GENERIC, ("Error: WSAStartup failed with error: {}", error));
    return;
}

if (LOBYTE(data.wVersion) != 2 || HIBYTE(data.wVersion) != 2)
{
    kzLogError(KZ_LOG_CATEGORY_GENERIC, ("Error: System could not support WinSock 2.2."));

    if (WSACleanup() == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        kzLogError(KZ_LOG_CATEGORY_GENERIC, ("Error: Winsock cleanup error: {}", WSAGetLastError()));
    }
    return;
}

SOCKET s = INVALID_SOCKET;

if ((s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    kzLogError(KZ_LOG_CATEGORY_GENERIC, ("Error: Socket creation failed with error: {}", WSAGetLastError()));

    if (WSACleanup() == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        kzLogError(KZ_LOG_CATEGORY_GENERIC, ("Error: Winsock cleanup error: {}", WSAGetLastError()));
    }
    return;
}

int bytesRecv = 0;
ReceiveData receiveData;
struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
int server_addr_len = sizeof(server_addr);

memset((char *)&server_addr, 0, server_addr_len);
server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
server_addr.sin_port = htons(2010);
server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

memset((char *)&receiveData, 0, sizeof(ReceiveData));

if (sendto(s, “hello”, strlen(“hello”), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &server_addr, server_addr_len) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    kzLogError(KZ_LOG_CATEGORY_GENERIC, ("Error: unable to send hello to server: {}", WSAGetLastError()));
}

while (bytesRecv != SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    bytesRecv = recvfrom(s, (char*)&receiveData, sizeof(ReceiveData), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &server_addr, &server_addr_len);
    if (bytesRecv > 0)
    {
        // parse the data
    }
    else
    {
        if (bytesRecv == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            kzLogError(KZ_LOG_CATEGORY_GENERIC, ("Error: Reading data: {}", WSAGetLastError()));
        }
    }
}

if (closesocket(s) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    kzLogError(KZ_LOG_CATEGORY_GENERIC, ("Error: Unable to close socket: {}", WSAGetLastError()));
}

if (WSACleanup() == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    kzLogError(KZ_LOG_CATEGORY_GENERIC, ("Error: Winsock cleanup error: {}", WSAGetLastError()));
}
```

Comment: What is the IP address of the server you want to send to, and what IP address have you told your socket to send to ?

Comment: There is some working UDP client-server code here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51038991/5743288

Comment: @nos This is a connectionless UDP client so in theory it shouldn't care what the server's IP is. `INADDR_ANY` tells the socket to accept data from any IP address communicating over the specified port.

Comment: @PaulSanders the code you linked to appears to be doing the same thing I am. And might be a server side implementation. They call `bind` when receiving data from wherever. `sendto` implicitly binds the socket to the port so theoretically I shouldn't need to do that.

Comment: @cHorse Well, but the first thing you do after creating the socket and initialized `server_addr` is a `sendto()` call, so I wonder where you are sending it to when the address is specified as INADDR_ANY. (Indeed, you.can't do that. When you want to send data to a server, you need to specify its address, which for UDP is an IP address and a port number - and when you want to receive data on that socket, whether you define yourself as a client or a server, you have to call bind() first, so your socket gets an address that the peer can send to).

Comment: @nos truthfully I only plan on receiving data from the server not actually send it any. Hence the "hello" message. The only reason I am making the call to `sendto` is because it implicitly binds the socket to the port. If I use `bind` instead `recvfrom` throws a `WSAEINVAL` error.

Comment: @cHorse then you are likely using `bind` or `recvfrom` incorrectly. Please show that code

Comment: @RemyLebeau replace the `sendto` in the above code with `bind(s, (SOCKADDR *)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr))`

Comment: @cHorse works fine for me. Please show a [mcve] where it does not work for you. `recvfrom()` would report `WSAEINVAL` if `bind()` failed