# How can I differentiate between windows 7 and windows xp or other windows in a C program?

Tags: c, windows, winapi

and also a 32bit OS from a 64bit OS?
Are there some #ifdef I can use to detect the actual OS version and whether it is 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: What toolchain/compiler are you using? I wouldn't use an `#ifdef` to detect XP vs. Windows 7, but you might have to for 32-bit vs. 64-bit. But there are probably better ways than an `#ifdef` to make your code 64-bit clean and portable...

Comment: Take a look at [Detect whether current Windows version is 32 bit or 64 bit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/601089/detect-whether-current-windows-version-is-32-bit-or-64-bit) and [How can I detect the operating system in C/C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/430424/how-can-i-detect-the-operating-system-in-c-c)

Comment: You want to determine at compile time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At compile time you can use the [`WINVER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa383745) & [`_WIN64`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) macro's, though this info is for the OS(es) being targeted, not the OS being compiled on.

At runtime you can use [`GetVersionEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724451%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get OS version info and [`IsWOW64Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684139%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to determine if you are running on 64 or 32 bit.